# Jquery is hiding my content but wont show it on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a bit of jquery to hide some content on my webpage until a button is clicked. The jquery is hiding my content just fine but no matter how many times I click the button, it wont show back up again and I cant figure out what I have done wrong! Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hidden-samples").hide();
  $('.access-content').click(function() {
    $('#hidden-samples').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hidden-samples">Samples</div>

<a class="access-content">Show Samples</a>
```

Comment: is your click event firing?

Comment: plz add your html

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Your code works just fine with some basic HTML. Problem must be elsewhere, but not in the code snippet you've shown us here. Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/397461/

Comment: $('.access-content').click listens for clicks on any elements that have class access-content that are already present on the page.  If you're trying to select id=access-content use $('#access-content'), if you are dynamically adding the element later, use $(document).on("click", ".access-content", function() { ...  })

Comment: The code works if you load jQuery. Perhaps you do not? Also there can be only one $("#hidden-samples") since IDs need to be unique

Comment: Your code also works with your HTML. See jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/397467/

Comment: HTML has been added and no, the click event is not firing. Although occasionally it will go through.

Comment: I am loading jquery and the fiddles you all have been posting seem to work. There must be something else on the page preventing the click event from registering

Comment: Do you have more than one link and more than one div you are trying to show?

Comment: I do not but I think I have figured it out is has something to do with the placement of the text I want to click. Moving it elsewhere on the page fixes everything.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `show()` use `toggle()` method. Please check the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hidden-samples").hide();
  $('.access-content').click(function() {
    $('#hidden-samples').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hidden-samples">Samples</div>

<a class="access-content">Show Samples</a>
```

Comment: considering the question, why is this any different? toggle() does the same as .show() in this scenario

Comment: How do you make the element hide again after show() is triggered?

Comment: That is not the question

Comment: "The jquery is hiding my content just fine but no matter how many times I click the button, it wont show back up again" - what this line says then?

Comment: am I missing something here?, acording to the OP's code, the event does not get fired and the div #hidden-samples does not show, there is not a single word in the question about hide on click, so, if you suggest this, please explain what it does so this guy does not get more confused

Comment: Why on earth would `.toggle()` work if `.show()` doesn't work?

Comment: Cool guys, thanks for your efforts to make me realise the question :D

Comment: Thanks for the response but if the click event isnt working then the method I use doesnt really matter. I actually tried moving around the text I wanted to click to somewhere else on my page and it works just fine. Something about the placement is blocking the click event from registering